# Open Home Page editable when Admin enter

Tags: javascript, php

I validate logins and I show a message saying "Welcome" when the admin enters but I want to open Home Page editable in this validation.

```
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
{
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Welcome!')
        window.location.href='Home.html'
        document.body.contentEditable = true;
        </SCRIPT>");
exit();
}
else{
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Palavra passe e username incorretos. Volte a introduzir')
        window.location.href='Home.html'
        </SCRIPT>");
exit();
```

If - When is admin I want to open the Home Page editable

Else - When is not admin I want to open the Home Page not editable

I try this but it didn't work:

```
document.body.contentEditable = true;
```

Comment: [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

You need to send it as string:

```
editable = document.body;
element.contentEditable = "true";
```

According to [Mozilla's `HTMLElement.contentEditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.contentEditable).